# Does 23andMe limit matches?

Tags: dna, 23andme

Out of 1500 DNA matches, none are more distant than estimated 5th cousin (15 Centimorgans). Do 23andMe have a 15 Centimorgan cutoff, or a cutoff of the number of matches that is limiting how many relatives I'm seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are seeing what is described at [While You Were Sleeping: 23andMe Disrupts DNA Relatives](https://throughthetreesblog.tumblr.com/post/631347932244951040/while-you-were-sleeping-23andme-disrupts-dna-relatives):

> 23andMe has tightened their DNA Relatives cap, reducing the maximum
> number of accessible DNA matches from 2000 to 1500, without directly
> notifying all customers. While in previous years, customers could
> overcome the 2000-match limit by sending all of one’s genetic
> relatives invitations to connect, 23andMe has made the new hard and
> fast 1500-match cap almost insurmountable.

Comment: Wow, that's absolutely appalling that you have to pay extra for what you can get from Ancestry DNA in the standard package.

Comment: Every DNA company has different offerings that they use to attract customers. Ancestry DNA does not give access to your segment matches or offer a chromosome browser like 23andMe and the other companies do.